# What is the symbol that looks like an up arrow?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

[image]

What are the symbols that look like an up arrow and a down arrow?

Comment: Maximum and minimum.

Comment: Up is min, down is max.

Comment: So it is, (k-1) or 4, whichever is the minimum?

Comment: @Kior $a\wedge b=\min\{a,b\}$ and $a\vee b=\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: These should be answers, not comments.

Comment: There are lots of competing meanings, including And and Or, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $a∧b$= $\min(a,b)$
 while $a∨b$=$\max(a,b)$. Therefore, the given summation is from $i=(k-4)$ or $1$ whichever is maximum to $i=(k-1)$ or $4$ , whichever is minimum.

Comment: FYI, `$\wedge \vee \max \min$` gives $\wedge \vee \max \min$